# Ontology/Satellite "satcat" is missing

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

Since two weeks I am missing the property [`satcat`](http://dbpedia.org/property/satcat) of the DBpedia class [`Satellite`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Satellite).

I am trying to get all satellites and filter it by the `satcat`. (It worked until October.)

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?satcat
WHERE {    ?subject ?x <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Satellite>.
           ?subject dbp:satcat ?satcat.

FILTER(?satcat = XXX )}
```

For example, extract information about http://dbpedia.org/resource/Envisat.

Do I have the opportunity to get some influence of the DBpedia database? Or can anybody fix the graph in the database? Or is there another common solution to extract a specific satellite out of dbpedia.org?

Comment: I think you should use the dbpedia live - it is a more updated version. This link has your dbp:satcat property. [link] http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Envisat

Comment: Thank you! I will try it as soon as the server is online again ("the web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time.
We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused.") :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have run into a glitch in the data of the latest DBpedia release, which [went live on October 14](https://twitter.com/pkleef/status/787037615761526784).

Probably best to raise this and issues like it to [dbpedia-discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-discussion/) and/or [dbpedia-developers](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/dbpedia-developers/).

I'd provide them with comparative links, e.g., the main [dbpedia.org/sparql](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fsatcat%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%20%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fx%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FSatellite%3E.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fsubject%20dbp%3Asatcat%20%3Fsatcat.%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%20FILTER%28%3Fsatcat%20%3D%20XXX%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on) vs [live.dbpedia.org/sparql](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fsatcat%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%20%20%20%3Fsubject%20%3Fx%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FSatellite%3E.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fsubject%20dbp%3Asatcat%20%3Fsatcat.%0D%0A%0D%0A%23%20FILTER%28%3Fsatcat%20%3D%20XXX%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on).